# Angular 6 & Electron: Using a mocked class for unit testing and extend the real class does not work

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, electron

i've tried to write a unit test in my electron app using jasmine and angular 6 but this way does not work. I have a service, that is not needed to be testet in my specific test of another service. So I decided to mock the first service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from '../../services/test/test.service';

@Injectable()
export class TestServiceMock extends TestService {

    private somePath: string;

    public isFileExistent(path: string): boolean {
        return path === '\\some\\kind\\of\\path\\some.json' ? true : false;
    }
}
```

i get the following error in visual studio code:

```
[ts] Class 'TestServiceMock' incorrectly extends base class 'TestService'.
Types have separate declarations of a private property 'somePath'.
```

i think i know that this error occurs, because the "somePath" member is somewhat different than in "TestService", but it really is not (in my understanding)! This is the "TestService":

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {ElectronService} from '../electron/electron.service';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

    private somePath: string;

    constructor(private electron: ElectronService) {
        this.somePath = this.electron.remote.app.getAppPath();
    }

    public isFileExistent(path: string): boolean {
        return // some boolean after a lot of operations not needed here
    }
}
```

last but not least the test i am writing which shows the following error:

```
[ts] Type 'typeof TestServiceMock' cannot be converted to type 'TestService'.
Property 'somePath' is missing in type 'typeof TestServiceMock'.
```

And the Test:

```
import { RealService } from './real.service';
import { TestServiceMock } from '../../response-models/test/test.service.mock';
import { TestService } from '../../services/test/test.service';

describe('RealService:', () => {
    let realservice: RealService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        realservice = new RealService(TestServiceMock as TestService);
    });

    it('should be available:', () => {
        expect(realservice).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mock service doesn't need to extend the real one. You can just have something like this:

```
export class TestServiceMock {
  public isFileExistent(path: string): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}
```

This defines all the public methods/fields that outside code can interact with and in the case of testing expects to find.

Then in your test file add the following to your beforEach block that angular provides by default:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: TestService, useValue: new TestServiceMock()} // <- this is what you need
  ]
}).compileComponents();
```

The line marked with the arrow in the comment essentially says provide `TestService` but actually use this value for it. That way components that expect to receive `TestService` get it but not the real one.

Using the `TestBed` you can then get a handle of the TestService that you injected (which is the fake one) and apply spies to it to manipulate the output of its methods.

I hope that helps.

Comment: After fiddleing around a bit this solution worked well for me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[The answer by @M Mansour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52618888/3635881) is solid for this question.

However, if you wanted to test this unit without using [TestBed](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBed), you can provide your class with spy object created by [`jasmine.createSpyObj()`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/jasmine.html) or a real object then `spyOn` functions that you wanted to mock instead.

Example of using real object then spy on the function:

```
import { RealService } from './real.service';
import { TestService } from '../../services/test/test.service';

describe('RealService:', () => {
  let realService: RealService;
  let testService: TestService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    testService = new TestService();
    realService = new RealService(TestService);
  });

  it('should call isFileExistent with valid path', () => {
    spyOn(testService, 'isFileExistent').and.returnValue(true);
    realService.doSomething();
    expect(testService.isFileExistent).toHaveBeenCalledWith('VALID_PATH');
  });
});
```

Of course, doing it this way may cause you to create all dependencies up above of the target unit. But I found it quicker to run and easier to understand.